# All Debian boot messages

Tags: debian, logging, boot, errors

How can the messages that scroll by when booting a Debian system be reviewed later?

In other words, how can I review absolutely **all** of them conveniently? That's the important point to the question; merely a subset of them is insufficient.

Some boot time messages are written only to `/var/log/daemon.log` and `/var/log/syslog`, where I have seen messages like: `udevd[240]: SYSFS{}= will be removed in a future udev version`.

In squeeze, these are not in `/var/log/dmesg`. Nor are they in `/var/log/boot` with setting `BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=yes` in `/etc/default/bootlogd` and package `bootlogd` installed.

For more details on `rsyslogd`'s various logging locations see your `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bootup messages pass by so fleetingly that, for some, one might not be sure what they say. You may wish to check all the files where they might be logged, in addition to the usual (well-known) log files, for verification purposes (at least).

On Debian, logs generally are kept in directory `/var/log`.

After booting, what changed there today (which files) can be seen in the Bash shell by:

`` sudo ls -ld --sort=time `sudo find /var/log -type f -daystart -ctime 0 | sed -r 's/^.*\.([0-9]+|old|gz)$//g'` ``

The scrolling output may contain interesting strings like 'will be removed'. Here's how to find them:

`` sudo grep -ilF 'will be removed' `sudo find /var/log -type f -daystart -ctime 0 | sed -r 's/^.*\.([0-9]+|old|gz)$//g' | sort` > log-list; sudo nano `cat log-list` ``

Boot-time logging can be [enabled](http://go2linux.garron.me/bootlogd-to-read-boot-console-messages) by:

`apt-get install bootlogd`

and edit `/etc/default/bootlogd` to contain

```
BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=yes
```

Unfortunately, bootlogd seems [unavailable](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=bootlogd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) on squeeze.

For color information, see [here](http://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd).

Comment: As of Wheezy, bootlogd no longer requires the `/etc/default/bootlogd` config file, see [here](https://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd).

Answer (score 13):

The boot messages come in two parts: those that come from the kernel (loading drivers, detecting partitions, etc) and those that come from the services starting up (`[ OK ] Starting Apache...`).  The kernel messages are stored in `/var/log/kern.log` and can also be accessed from the kernel's own log buffer with the `dmesg` program.

The userspace messages are not stored anywhere unless you install the [`bootlogd`](http://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd) package.  It will log the service startup messages in `/var/log/boot`  Note if you have the "fancy" boot messages (the colored `[ OK ]` `[FAIL]` etc messages), it will log the terminal escape codes in the file.  You can disable the fancy boot messages by creating an [`/etc/lsb-base-logging.sh`](http://ircbots.debian.net/factoids/factoid.php?key=fancytty) shell script which defines `FANCYTTY=0` in it.

Comment: Rather than disabling the colored messages, you can view them using commands like sed 's/\^\[/\o33/g;s/\[1G\[/\[27G\[/' /var/log/boot | less -r - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757823/display-file-with-escaped-color-codes-boot-messages-from-bootlog-daemon/19011140#19011140

Answer (score 1):

In 2021, I couldn't make `bootlogd` work as expected in debian buster. I installed it, enabled the service (with some difficulties similar to those described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804946/systemctl-how-to-unmask)), rebooted several times, but there was still nothing in `/var/log/boot` (except the hint that nothing had been logged yet).

It turned out that `bootlogd` is not compatible with `systemd`. But it is `systemd` itself which came to rescue: `journalctl --list-boots` lists the boot processes it is aware of, while `journalctl -b N` outputs the log of boot process `N`. To output the log of the last boot process, use `N=0`, i.e. `journalctl -b 0`. As far as I can tell, these logs include the messages of the kernel as well as those from the init system.

`journalctl -b` lists all details from all boot processes, but on my systems, it is only aware of the last boot process, so it doesn't make a difference. To be honest, I have no clue how to make the boot logs permanent so that it could output the logs for all of them instead of only the last one. But I'm usually interested only in the last boot process anyway, so this isn't a problem for me.

I am pretty sure that `journalctl -b` does not only work on debian, but on nearly all distributions which use `systemd`.

Comment: Go to a search engine and type in: How to make systemd journal persistent. You will have your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. However, I actually didn't ask that question. To cite myself: *... But I'm usually interested only in the last boot process anyway, so this isn't a problem for me. ...* My post was just meant as new answer in 2021 to the OP's question from 2013, because the other answers are from 2013 as well and don't mention `journalctl -b`, which in 2021 IMHO is by far the easiest method to view the whole boot log.

Comment: Regarding "*I am pretty sure that `journalctl -b` does not only work on debian*": It works   flawlessly in a freshly-installed *Debian 11 bullseye*.

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds silly, but when none of the other options work and you're desperate, you can grab your phone and record your screen as it boots and then play back the video at reduced speed to review them.

This is not a good solution if you want to programmatically check your boot messages, but if you see an error during booting and you want to diagnose it, this solution works fine.